# Angular does not want to retrieve data from another table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a card that should display the details on the card, but the details of only one data table pull through.

Here is my code:

userServices.ts

```
getModules(): Observable<Module[]> {
    return this.http.get<Module[]>(this.baseUrl + 'modules');
  };
  getModule(id): Observable<Module> {
    return this.http.get<Module>(this.baseUrl + 'modules/' + id);
  }
```

course-detailcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from 'src/app/_models/course';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/_services/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from 'src/app/_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Module } from 'src/app/_models/module';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.css'],
})
export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
// modules: Module[];
module: Module;
course: Course;



  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data =>{
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.course = data['course'];
    });
    this.route.data.subscribe(data =>{
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.module = data['modules'];
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      console.log('modules', data['modules'])
    });

  }

}
```

course-detail component.html

```
    <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="tab-pannel">
               <tabset class="member-tabset">
                   <tab heading="About {{course.title}}:">
                         <h4>Modules:</h4>
                         <p>insert modules here</p>
                        <app-module-list >{{module.title}}</app-module-list> 
                         <p>{{module.title}}</p>
                         
                   </tab>
               </tabset>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Course-detail.resolver.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Course } from '../_models/course';
import { Resolve, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()

export class CourseDetaiResolver implements Resolve<Course> {
    constructor(private userService: UserService,
        private router: Router, private alertify: AlertifyService){}

        resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) : Observable<Course> {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
            return this.userService.getCourse(route.params['id']).pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    this.alertify.error('Problem retrieving data')
                    this.router.navigate(['/home/']);
                    return of (null)
                })
            );
        }
```

}

In Postman the data is showing correct, its just displaying it on the Angular side.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would like assistance if possible.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what exactly goes wrong. Only one course is shown instead of the multiple courses that you want to show? Could you try to go more in detail?

Comment: the course shows, it is the modules that do not want to display on the card.

Comment: post the data of  console.log('modules', data['modules'])?

Comment: Nope does not post when console.log. my C# data pulls through on Postman but Angular seems to have an error.

Comment: You don't seem to have a resolver or you haven't posted the code?

Comment: Hi Ruben, the very last code is my resolver in my post is the resolver.

Comment: keeps saying in console . log that module is undefined. i have made reference to the interfaces